# combining strings from muliple rows in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I obtain the below output in sql server 2012.

Table

```
ID  | Values|
1      a  
1      b    
1      c   
2      d      
2      e
```

The output should be such that the first row has a fixed number of  values(2) seperated by comma and the next row has the remaining values seperated by comma

ID

```
ID  | Values|
1      a,b  
1      c    
2      d,e
```

Each id should contain maximum two values in a single row.The remaining values should come in the next row.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: How come you want (a,b) and c, instead of (a,c) and b, or (b,c) and a?

Comment: I think this needs a little more context to provide any real/helpful answers

Answer (score 1):

Try to use my code:

```
use db_test;

create table dbo.test567
(
    id int,
    [values] varchar(max)
);

insert into dbo.test567
values 
    (1, 'a'),
    (1, 'b'),
    (1, 'c'),
    (2, 'd'),
    (2, 'e')

with cte as (
    select 
        id, 
        [values], 
        row_number() over(partition by id order by [values] asc) % 2 as rn1,
        (row_number() over(partition by id order by [values] asc) - 1) / 2 as rn2
    from dbo.test567
), cte2 as (
select 
    id, max(case when rn1 = 1 then [values] end) as t1, max(case when rn1 = 0 then [values] end) as t2
from cte
group by id, rn2
)
select 
    id, 
    case 
        when t2 is not null then concat(t1, ',', t2)
        else t1
    end as [values]
from cte2
order by id, [values]
```